# Getting OSM maps in Equirectangular Projection via osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to import some OSM data into psql as equirectangular projection using osm2pgsql with the following command:

```
osm2pgsql -c -d osm -S /usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style -l /OPENSTREETMAP/south-america-latest.osm.pbf
```

However, it fails with this error:

```
Projection code failed to initialise
```

I have installed the latest version of the PROJ framework from [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 1:

Running 'select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=4326;' on the database produces this:

```
 srid | auth_name | auth_srid |                                                                                                                              srtext                                                                                                                              |              proj4text               
------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 4326 | EPSG      |      4326 | GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]] | +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
(1 row)
```

Comment: What does ``select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=4326;`` run on the database report?

Comment: Paul Norman: see Edit 1 above.

Comment: Did you install osm2pgsql from source? It *looks* like the error is coming from osm2pgsql, not PostGIS. If your proj framework and osm2pgsql both came packaged, it's possible they're not talking to each other properly. Building osm2pgsql from source would probably fix that. If not, you might need to file an issue at https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues

Comment: I just tried to install from source (following the instructions ending with './autogen.sh && ./configure && make'. Now when I try to run the command, it says: '-bash: /usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql: is a directory'

Comment: You need to specify the osm2pgsql you compiled, probably with ``~/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -c -d osm -S /usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style -l /OPENSTREETMAP/south-america-latest.osm.pbf``. The exact path will depend on where you downloaded osm2pgsql and built it.

Comment: Aha! This is now working, thank you so much! So I did need to compile from source. What I don't understand is why when you run the homebrew install of osm2pgsql you can then just run the command 'osm2pgsql' from anywhere, without specifying the program's location (but then there are almost infinite things I don't understand about command line stuff in Terminal...)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your version of osm2pgsql is built for the version of postgis you have.

There were some major changes in postgis 2.0.

It might help to run the legacy.sql to add the old functions again, see

https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#legacy_faq

---

**EDIT**

Second choice:

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/16175/nominatim-installation-problem-projection-code-failed

https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@openstreetmap.org/msg09334.html

comes with the same error, because the proj lib can not be found. This was a Windows system, but make sure osm2pgsql can find the proj lib.

Comment: I ran the legacy.sql command on the database (like this: psql -d osm -f /usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.1.1/share/postgis/legacy.sql) and it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Does it fail with -m instead of -l too?

Comment: No, it works fine with -m. But that puts the data in there in Mercator, which is no good.

Comment: You could reproject the database after import if everything else fails. Can you run the tests on command line from the mailing list article I added to my question? Seems that proj is present, but can not be found.

Comment: I ran the test and it produced the correct result, so it can't be the same issue they were having there...

Comment: Here is some more on your topic: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/15. I think you should contact Dane there, he is the author of osm2pgsql.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK the most OSM tools rely on a 4326 projection, so it's not a wise idea to change the DB schema to a different one. Instead you could write a small wrapper or use e.g. Geoserver to reproject the geometries per request.

Comment: There's nothing wrong, EPSG:4326 _is_ a equirectangular projection.